# add IIS 8 certificate mappings programatically

Tags: iis, vbscript

I've tried several ways of doing this, but I have not succeeded yet.

I tried unsuccessfully to adapt this script from Microsoft. There is an error somewhere I couldn't find. Could someone help me?

```
set arguments = WScript.Arguments
if (arguments.length < 3 or arguments.length > 4) then
    WScript.Echo("Usage certmap.vbs <.cer file name> <userName> <password> [site]")
    WScript.Quit(0)
end if

certName = arguments(0)
user = arguments(1)
password = arguments(2)
site = "Default Web Site"

if (arguments.length = 4) then
    site = arguments(3)
end if

const forReading = 1

set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
cer = ""

set f = fso.OpenTextFile(certName, forReading)
s = f.ReadLine()

if (s <> "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----") then
    f.Close
    shell.Run "cmd /C certutil -encode -f " + certName + " certToMap64.cer", 0, true
    set f = fso.OpenTextFile("certToMap64.cer", forReading)
    s = f.ReadLine()
end if

do while f.AtEndOfStream <> true
    s = f.ReadLine
    if f.AtEndOfStream <> true then
        cer = cer + s
    end if
loop

f.Close

WScript.Echo cer

configPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/" + site
configSectionName = "system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication"

set adminManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager")
set iisCertMap = adminManager.GetAdminSection(configSectionName, configPath)

iisCertMap.Properties.Item("enabled").Value = "true"
iisCertMap.Properties.Item("oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled").Value = "true"

set oneToOneMappingsElement = iisCertMap.ChildElements.Item("oneToOneMappings")
set mapping = oneToOneMappingsElement.collection.CreateNewElement()

mapping.Properties.Item("certificate").Value = cer
mapping.Properties.Item("enabled").Value = "true"
mapping.Properties.Item("userName").Value = user
mapping.Properties.Item("password").Value = password

oneToOneMappingsElement.Collection.AddElement(mapping)
adminManager.CommitChanges()
```

Once the code is copied within certmappings.vbs and executed with the corresponding parameters it shows an error at last line with message: "Keyset does not exist." I am wondering the error should be somewhere before that and it appears when commit is done.

I am Using Windows 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.9600.16384. This script is supossed to work in IIS7.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have found a workaround by using a command line utility which comes along with IIS8.

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webserver/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /+"onetoonemappings.[userName='midominio\jgrodrigo',password='P@ssw0rd',certificate='MIIJhzCCCG+gAwIBAgIQVOKUGessUOCW...
```

It works fine. Hope it is useful for the next guy with such a problem.

Cheers!